# Posting a polymorpic object to a controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, polymorphism

I have successfully mapped my polymorphic structure into the view, however, when I am trying to post user input for a particular derived object, it is not recognizing the derived type in  the controller action...

**Top-level view for the base type:**

```
@model  InformationRequestViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostInformationRequest", "SomeController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
}
```

**View for the derived type:**

```
@model  ActiveServiceInformationRequestViewModel

<label>Start date:</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StartDate, new { @class = "u-full-width" })

<label>End date:</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EndDate, new { @class = "u-full-width" })
```

**Post action:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostInformationRequest(InformationRequestViewModel model)
{
    if(model is ActiveServiceInformationRequestViewModel)
    {
        // IT IS NOT DIPPING INTO THIS LOGIC!

        // Do something with this particular concrete type...
    }

    // More derived type checks and relevant logic here...

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**Base view model:**

```
public class InformationRequestViewModel
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

**Derived view model:**

```
    public class ActiveServiceInformationRequestViewModel : InformationRequestViewModel
    {
          public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
          public DateTime EndDate {get; set;}
    }
```

Comment: View for the derived type references StartDate twice and not end date

Comment: I guess (currently not able to test it) you have to define an overload method for this. I assume your model will be deserialized based upon the class defined in the method signature, and therefor be of type InformationRequestViewModel.

Comment: So you think I would need to create a separate POST action for each derived type?

Comment: I don't think you can do this by default as the MVC model binder will just try to create a `InformationRequestViewModel` for you, there's no way for it to know that you are posting a derived model. You could possibly get away with it if you made your own model binder.